# URLSession really slow response from request even with Dispatch Queue

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am using the DispatchQueue method but I am not experiencing faster response times, am I calling it wrong?

```
func httpRequest(_ collection: String, httpSuccess: @escaping ((_ data: Data) -> Void), httpFailure:((_ error: NSError) -> Void)?, method: String!, params: String? = nil) {

 ....


let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
     print("0")      
     if let responseError = error as NSError! {
     print("1")
         DispatchQueue.main.async { print("2"); httpFailure?(responseError) }
     } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
         print("3")
         if httpResponse.statusCode < 200 || httpResponse.statusCode > 300 {
            let statusError = NSError(domain:"domain.com", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP request returned status \(httpResponse.statusCode)"])
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  httpFailure?(statusError) }
         } else {
            print("5")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { print("6");  httpSuccess(data!) }
         }
     }
 })
 task.resume()
}
```

Comment: your server is responding fast?

Comment: Yes it is responding fast

Comment: check that your code is entering in your first `if` or in the `else if`, if don't there is your problem, you can check by adding debugPrints

Comment: You're right it's not doing my prints inside the IF. Why is that and how is it still executing the code inside it? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: please update your question code with the debugPrints and mark which is not printed?

Comment: I'm an idiot, It is printing out in this order 0, 3, 5, 6

Comment: then is fine, i don´t know why is retarding the update in the UI then

Comment: Could it have something to do with my method signature?